# How to find values ​in quotes using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file with the following content:

```
"X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s";
```

I want to extract the returned results Output as:

```
MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s
```

Tks Everybody!

Comment: cut -d = test.txt -f 2 | sed s/\"//g | sed s/\;//g
Another alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `awk` idea, assuming this is the only line in the file:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{print $4}' file
MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s
```

If there are other lines and you wish to focus only on the line with the string "X-Apple-I-MD-M":

Input file:

```
$ cat file
some line to ignore
    "X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s";
other line to ignore and "with" some "quotes"
```

New `awk` idea:

```
$ pattern='X-Apple-I-MD-M'
$ awk -v ptn="${pattern}" -F'"' '$2==ptn {print $4}' file
MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s
```

And saving the `awk` result in a variable:

```
$ mystring=$(awk ... )
$ echo "${mystring}"
MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s
```

**NOTE:** keep in mind if there are multiple matching lines in `file` then `${mystring}` will contain a multi-line value (eg, `line1match\nline2match\nline3match`

Comment: Before "X-Apple-I-MD-M" there are some spaces (I put it in the code tag it is removed) 

I use awk '{print substr ($0, 25, length($0) - 26) }' frequently causes errors due to changing whitespace. 
That's why I wanted to find another code. 

Note: this value does not change "X-Apple-I-MD-M"

Comment: @KênhVuiĐểHọc if you mean there is white space before the first `"` ... that should be ok, this code should still work as it looks at the strings between the double quotes (ie, fields #2 and #4 when parsing the line as `"`-delimited data); I've updated my sample file to include leading white space and the `awk` code still generates the desired result

Comment: the case arises, sometimes the file has no quotes, sometimes there are quotes: "X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s"; and "X-Apple-I-MD-M" = MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s; .Can you handle it?

Comment: I used sed: sed 's/"//g' to remove all quotes, how should the main command be corrected now?

Comment: please update the question with a (more) complete set of sample inputs; alternatively, seeing how this question explicitly refers to values in quotes, consider creating a new question (with the more complete set of sample inputs)

Answer (score 1):

I always like `sed`.

```
$: echo '"X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s";'| sed -E 's/^.*= *"([^"]+)" *; *$/\1/'
MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s
```

if it's a file,

```
$: sed -E 's/^.*= *"([^"]+)" *; *$/\1/' file
MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep(1)`, something like.

```
grep -Po '(?<="X-Apple-I-MD-M" = ").*(?=";)' <<< '"X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s";'
```

---

If it is in a file.

```
grep -Po '(?<="X-Apple-I-MD-M" = ").*(?=";)' file.txt
```

Comment: I try and output: usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: If you're on a non Linux system, then you need to install GNU `grep`

Answer (score 0):

If your content is consistent, an ugly solution is:

```
VAL='"X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "MR7v7ctwW0yr3mAUY3rAluXgOReA4CIn1JWJS2ba1s";'
echo $VAL
echo $VAL | awk '{split($0, a, " = "); print(substr(a[2], 2, length(a[2]) - 3))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing by the `bash` tag, this is probably supposed to be in pure Bash, without external processes…? Two (somewhat) random options:

```sh
while IFS='"' read _ _ _ code _; do
  echo "$code"
done
```

```sh
while read line; do
  line="${line#\"*\" = \"}"
  line="${line%\";}"
  echo "$line"
done
```